# What the part of speech of some phrases of the sentence

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What the part of speech of the word "open" in the next sentence:

> He had only time to back away before the thick wooden doors swung open, hinges protesting loudly.

What the meaning of the second part of the sentence "hindges protesting loudly"?

Comment: Please try to ask one question per post, if possible.  Since someone's already posted an answer to your question about *hinges protesting loudly*, you could post about *open* separately and show what research you've done and why you're confused about the part of speech.

Comment: "Open" is an adjective functioning as an optional predicative adjunct. "Swung open" entails that the door swung and it became open. "Hinges protesting loudly" means that the hinges were stiff and noisy as a result of being old and/or inadequately lubricated.

Answer (score 1):

> Hinges protesting loudly

This means that the hinges were stiff or rusted, so there was some friction or resistance when the door was opening that created some noise.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the sentence, "hinges protesting loudly," is figurative.

The author is personifying the hinges in order to draw a connection between the sound the hinges are making and the sound that people make while protesting. Suspense is built in this way (by using a combination of lengthy syntax and powerful imagery).

**Basically, it is just a fancy way of saying the door's hinges were creaking loudly.**

Answer (score 0):

"Open" is an **adjective** functioning as an optional predicative adjunct.

"Swung open" entails that the door swung and it became open. "Hinges protesting loudly" means that the hinges were stiff and noisy as a result of being old and/or inadequately lubricated. –
BillJ